# Merc C class 2.2 CDI W203 tire skipping

Tags: tires, suspension, mercedes-benz, control-arm

So i have a problem with my car for some reason when turning sharp (>= 90 deg) turns my front tires seem to skip out with a rubbery pong sound like the tires bouncing back along the road surface.

This is ever since i got the control arms (wishbone's?) replaced but recently it's started getting a lot worse. i check air pressure at the front tiers are at 30 PSI, as they should be but for some reason the drivers side looks low still, so today i swapped the back and front tires over to see if the tie wall was dodgy and not supporting. however it has done the same thing with the swapped tires and the one i moved to the back looks fine and is supporting the back of the car perfectly.

After speaking with my brother we have come to the conclusion that it must be the shocks / main suspension struts would we have come to the correct conclusion could the struts cause this?

**the control arms i replaced**

[image: control arms kit]

Comment: Have you had the alignment checked?

Comment: alignment is slightly out as passenger side is Waring slightly to the outside but not enough to cause problems as there is no steering wobble at 80MPH-90MPH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm, it was the shock absorbers replaced them with my brother and the jumping has stopped.